# I have an array with postive and negative values how can i separate it in php?

Tags: php, arrays

this array contains positive and negative values in it.

```
$arr_pn = array( 1, -1, 2, 10,-15 );
```

My question is how to separate all negative values and store in an array and positive values in one more array?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you really have now idea how to even `foreach` through it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$arr_p = array();
$arr_n = array(); 
foreach ($arr_pn as $val) {
    if ($val >= 0) {
        $arr_p[] = $val;
    }
    else {
        $arr_n[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Resisted downvoting for space between identifier and brackets ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your immediate reply. I'm scratching my head from the past one hour for this solution!!

Comment: @webbiedave: which identifier/brackets are you talking about, the square brackets? Is it the norm to remove that space? (I couldn't find anything about it in the Zend coding style guide)

Comment: Yes. The index (including an empty one) is needed to fully identify an array element so it should be butted up against the identifier: `$arr_p[]`. Even more so in PHP 5.4 as arrays can now be created with the new syntax: `$array = ['foo'];` Nothing is mentioned of this in the Zend guide but it should be!

Comment: All right, updated! Do you know of any document which describes these things? The Zend guide misses quite a lot, it doesn't even explain that there should be a space between foreach and opening bracket.

Comment: I don't know of any style guide that talks about array brackets. Maybe you should suggest it to them! The PEAR standard mentions the space between the control keyword and opening parenthesis though.

Answer (score 4):

#### Reducing Original Array

Rather than creating two arrays, just remove all of the negative numbers, leaving only positives:

```
$neg = array();
foreach( $arr_pn as $key => $num ) {
  if ( $num < 0 ) {
    unset( $arr_pn[ $key ] );
    array_push( $neg, $num );
  }
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/TCwXYn2P

One warning is that the original array will have missing keys. So consider this if you plan on counting through them. You could use [`array_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-key the array:

```
$arr_pn = array_values( $arr_pn );
```

#### Two Resulting Arrays

If you wanted two arrays:

```
$neg = array();
$pos = array();

foreach( $arr_pn as $num ) {
  $num < 0 
    ? array_push( $neg, $num ) 
    : array_push( $pos, $num ) ;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/pHVyTRMc

Answer (score 3):

```
$arr_pn = array( 1, -1, 2, 10,-15 );

$arrayPositive = array_filter($arr_pn, function($value) { return $value > 0.0; } );
$arrayNegative = array_filter($arr_pn, function($value) { return $value < 0.0; } );

var_dump($arrayPositive);
var_dump($arrayNegative);
```

Comment: Very scannable. Best answer IMO.